# RequestTemplate call returns a SigningGroupID of 0

Tags: c#, soap, docusignapi

I have a template in DocuSign that contains a SigningGroup as one of its recipients. when I tried to retrieve this template via C#/SOAP, the value of SigningGroupId is 0 and SigningGroupIdSpecified   false. Is there any setting I need to enable or a flag I need to set to true to be able to correctly retrieve the recipient's SigningGroupId?

Below is the code to retrieve the template

```
dsApi.RequestTemplate(templateId, false);
```

dsApi obviously contains the reference to the SOAP API loaded in C#

Image below shows the SigningGroupId value returned by the API

[image]

Thank you and good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its not possible to get it via SOAP API, instead you can get the same via REST API

```
GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/recipients
```

Details are available at [RecipientList](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/TemplateRecipients/list/)

Response will look like:

```
{
            "creationReason": "sender",
            "isBulkRecipient": "false",
            "name": "TestSigningGrp",
            "email": "",
            "signingGroupId": "27343",
            "signingGroupName": "TestSigningGrp",
            "signingGroupUsers": [
                {
                    "userName": "Test1",
                    "userId": "a832164e-0da7-449c-9405-be21632564a4",
                    "email": "email1@gmail.com",
                    "uri": "/users/a832164e-0da7-449c-9405-be21632564a4"
                },
                {
                    "userName": "Test2",
                    "userId": "68139c8e-8dee-4b51-8b78-842e470ee5b3",
                    "email": "email2@gmail.com",
                    "uri": "/users/68139c8e-8dee-4b51-8b78-842e470ee5b3"
                }
            ],
            "recipientId": "23764479",
            "recipientIdGuid": "5474c7d9-1548-42a4-99ee-dba6ea87fdda",
            "requireIdLookup": "false",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "note": "",
            "roleName": "SigningRole",
            "status": "created",
            "declinedReason": "",
            "deliveryMethod": "email"
        }
```

Comment: how is it not possible? Are they not supporting signingGroupId in SOAP? I can retrieve the field signingGroupId, it's just not populated properly.

Comment: I think same domain is used in different response but this value is not populated in this API call. If you are in your development phase, I would suggest to move your code to Rest API as all new features and new Product Development in DocuSign happen only in REST API. REST API has lot more features compared to SOAP API.

Comment: sadly, the code is years old and moving to REST would hold a lot of stuff in production. Is there a SOAP call where we can retrieve this value? thanks.

Comment: Can you please share why you need this signinggroupId back from template? What are you planning to do after receiving the signingGroupId?

Comment: So that I can add it as one of the recipients in the envelope.

Comment: You do not need to add signinggroup explictly as a recipient while creating an envelope. Using CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms operation and create a compositetemplate by referring a servertemplate which has signinggroup. And DocuSign will automatically add signing group as another recipient in the envelope from the template referred in the Server Template.

Comment: thanks for bearing with me here. Using a servertemplate is not an option. From the templates list of signers, I retrieve that using the RequestTemplate method and Update some fields in the Signers and create an InlineTemplate instead to send the envelope using CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms. I'll be unable to do this using a servertemplate.

Comment: Composite template will help you in doing the same, you will get recipient roles from server template. Then you can replace the server template document with your document in the InlineDocument or document node using proper sequence number. Did you get it? Try using composite template in CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms. Then in document node put the document which you want to add in the envelope, InlineTemplate should have sequence value higher than you put in the server template.

Comment: you will see signing group is added in the envelope from server template but actual document which is added in the envelope is the one present in the document node.

Comment: adding the servertemplate worked!!! awesome suggestion @amit-k-bist . I'd accept your answer but it's just a comment on an actual answer comment which is not the solution.

Comment: to add, the RequestTemplate function currently does not support the SigningGroupId feature hence why the SigningGroupId will always be 0. I've talked to a DocuSign dev directly and he did mention about opening a Request/Bug to support it in the SOAP API Call.

Answer (score 0):

I've accepted as an answer the comment of @amit but the actual answer is the 8th comment of that answer, also by @amit.